# How to run a landing page with one section using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, dashboard

I have a login form with which the user accesses the dashboard. I want when I click a button on the landing page (.html) that the application redirects to the login form!

How can I run it with localhost:5000 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you have to use history object from the props.

For example state-less component:

```
const LandingPage = ({ history }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => history.push('/login')}>Login</button> };
```

Obviously you have to have a valid route.

For example in App.jsx:

```
<Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
```

Comment: @IIya can I use that with reactjs ans nodejs ?

Comment: @CodeLover Of course. The strategy is different though. On your back-end (node.js) create a route for accepting a POST request from your front-end (react.js). In other words, by clicking on Login button you are making AJAX request to your back-end ('/login') route. Take a look on axios library for making requests.